# Expansion of ideal gas in isothermic conditions

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, erratum

I'm doing this problem and I get a different value than the answer in a book. I'm not sure if the book is wrong or me.

> At a constant temperature of $298~\mathrm{K}$, calculate $\Delta S_{\mathrm{sys}}$ and $\Delta S_{\mathrm{univ}}$ for the free expansion of $3.0~\mathrm{L}$ of an ideal gas at $1.0~\mathrm{atm}$ to $11.0~\mathrm{L}$.

### My solution

Firstly, I calculated the moles of gas $n$:

$$\begin{align}
n &= \frac{PV}{RT} \\
&= \frac{(1~\mathrm{atm}) \cdot (3.0~\mathrm{L})}{(0.0821~\mathrm{L~atm~mol^{-1}~K^{-1}})\cdot(298~\mathrm{K})} \\
&= 0.1226~\mathrm{mol}
\end{align}$$

Secondly, I used this to calculate $\Delta S$:

$$\begin{align}
\Delta S &= nR \ln{\frac{V_2}{V_1}} \\
&= (0.1226~\mathrm{mol}) \cdot (0.0821~\mathrm{L~atm~mol^{-1}~K^{-1}}) \cdot \ln{\left(\frac{11.0~\mathrm{L}}{3.0~\mathrm{L}}\right)} \\
&= 0.0130~\mathrm{L~atm~K^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

However, the answer in the book is $0.027~\mathrm{L~atm~K^{-1}}$. I'm not sure if that's an error.

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in your arguments. Is the question you state all that was given? No other minor conditions?

Comment: I agree.  I get the same answer as you guys.

Comment: @SatwikPasani, I copied it exactly as given in the book. I forgot to mention that the book is "Study Guide for Chemistry 5th Edition by Zumdahl" The author of the study guide is Paul B Kelter. Copyright 2000. ISBN: 0-395-98586-2  Might be a typo.